# Split UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, math, uibezierpath, curve

I'm having trouble figuring out how to implement the following requirement:

Users are allowed to draw an arbitrary UIBezierPath made from a bunch of points (which I have available), which can look something like this:

[image]

Now I need to be able to delete any of the intersections of the curve. So that in the end I get a results like:

[image]

However I need help figuring out how to do this. At first instance I tried code similar to this one (Warning: this is just a test, it might not even be correct or could crash).

```
-(void)splitPaths:(NSMutableArray *)sourcePoints paths:(NSMutableArray *)paths
{
NSLog(@"Splitting points: %d",sourcePoints.count);
for(int i= 0; i < sourcePoints.count ; i++)
{
    CGPoint pointOne = [[sourcePoints objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue];
    for(int j= i+1; j< sourcePoints.count; j++)
    {
        CGPoint pointTwo = [[sourcePoints objectAtIndex:j] CGPointValue];

        if(CGPointEqualToPoint(pointOne, pointTwo))
        {
            NSRange initialRange = NSMakeRange(0, i);
            NSRange pathRange = NSMakeRange(i, j - i);
            NSRange finalRange = NSMakeRange(j, sourcePoints.count - 1);

            NSArray *firstArray = [sourcePoints subarrayWithRange:initialRange];
            NSArray *pathArray = [sourcePoints subarrayWithRange:pathRange];
            NSArray *finalArray = [sourcePoints subarrayWithRange:finalRange];

            [paths addObject:pathArray];

            NSMutableArray *remainingPoints = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[firstArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:finalArray]];
            [self splitPaths:remainingPoints paths:paths];
        }
    }
}
}
```

Which is a recursive function that would split each "segment" of the curve. Hope you can get the idea of what I'm trying to do... However it seems that I don't have points accurate enough for the CGPointEqualToPoint to return YES.

So the question is if anybody got an idea on how to achieve this. Or maybe a better algorithm or example. It would be great.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You don't really have curved Bézier segments, only straight line segments, right? http://geomalgorithms.com/a09-_intersect-3.html#Short%20Survey might help, perhaps http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Sweep_line_2/Chapter_main.html as well.

Comment: Take a look at my answer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12909008/how-to-find-the-closing-pathtwo-line-intersection-in-iphone-sdk/12909571#12909571)